# View image from object ole db sql in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

i am looking for a way to display in classic asp an image stored in an ole object of a sql db.
I've been looking around for a while, and the only thing I've found is such a thing that I've readjusted for my needs.
Unfortunately, however, it does not work, you only see a small square with a central x.
Do you have a suggestion?
Thanks

```
<%@LANGUAGE = VBScript%>
```

<%
id = Request.Querystring("id")

```
Set Conn1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn1.open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=ARCA;Database=CDB_EVEREX;Uid=everex;Pwd=everex1989;"

Dim strSQL, Rs
Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Attrezzatura_Catalogo WHERE ID_Catalogo=" & id & ";"
Rs.Open strSQL, Conn1, 3, 1

' Clear out the existing HTTP header information
'Response.Expires = 0
'Response.Buffer = TRUE
'Response.Clear

' Change the HTTP header to reflect that an image is being passed.
Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"

Response.BinaryWrite Rs("Immagine") 
'Response.End

Rs.Close
Conn1.Close
Set Conn1 = Nothing
```

%>

Answer (score 0):

make sure stored data is binary and try this?

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader  "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file001.bmp"
Response.Clear
Response.BinaryWrite Rs("Immagine")
Response.Flush
%>
```

maybe stored data can be base64. if data base64 then type directly into img src

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I tried your suggestion by adapting the code as you suggested (if I understand correctly) but the problem is not solved, you always see only the square with the central x :(

```
<%@LANGUAGE = VBScript%>
```

<%
id = Request.Querystring("id")

```
Set Conn1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn1.open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=ARCA;Database=CDB_EVEREX;Uid=everex;Pwd=everex1989;"

Dim strSQL, Rs
Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Attrezzatura_Catalogo WHERE ID_Catalogo=" & id & ";"
Rs.Open strSQL, Conn1, 3, 1

Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader  "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file001.bmp"
Response.Clear
Response.BinaryWrite Rs("Immagine")
Response.Flush  

Rs.Close
Conn1.Close
Set Conn1 = Nothing
```

%>